Leak of memory Swift, XCode
I am trying to detect a memory leak in my app.
And I found a mark in the memory graph that i have a leak in NSMallocBlock. But I don't know if this is my mistake or not. enter image description here
Can someone help me understand what is mean? And what can I do yet?
